# How to create new partitions for a linux system that contains Logical volumes

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I am trying to add new partitions which are not logical volumes. But I have a system with logical volumes. I tried reducing the lv_home partition size using ‘lvresize’, and reduced a LV size by 5GB successfully. And I want to create new partition with that 5GB. But I am not able to find that space.

```
xvda 202:0 0 150G 0 disk
 ├─xvda1 202:1 0 500M 0 part /boot
 └─xvda2 202:2 0 149.5G 0 part
    ├─VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0 0 50G 0 lvm /
    ├─VolGroup-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1 0 3.9G 0 lvm [SWAP]
    └─VolGroup-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2 0 90.6G 0 lvm /home
```

I reduced lv_home from 95 to 90GB. Now where this free space is available?. When I tried to make partion using "fdisk xvda" it says no free sectors. I want to create 2 or 3 partitions using that 5GB. Would some one help me in doing that?

Comment: Probably this is what I am looking for: http://superuser.com/questions/734468/how-can-i-shrink-a-logical-volume-and-re-allocate-the-freed-space-into-a-new-pa

Answer (score 0):

I advise you this wiki page to get all relevant info on how LVM works, with examples and explanations:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM

It is all I needed when first had to deal with LVM.

In your example, when you free up some space from a logical volume, the space is freed for the Volume group, so it is only available for other logical volumes on the same group.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I followed a duplicate link and was partially successful.